# "The system cannot find the path specified" when compiling SASS

Tags: ruby, sass

I'm trying to learn SASS and so I have installed ruby through RubyInstaller and installed the sass gem.

I am able to type out my sass and have the compiler watch the file and write to another just fine, but every time I save my file I get

```
The system cannot find the path specified
C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++)
```

However everything works as intended, the styles are updated and compiled just fine, but it's quite annoying hitting ctrl+s and having that error keep popping up when it doesn't seem to be affecting anything.

How do I go about troubleshooting this?

Comment: Look in the settings for Notepad++, and search for how to operate Notepad++.

Comment: @7stud, Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Yes, you troubleshoot your problem by reading the Notepad++ docs: http://notepad-plus-plus.org/, reading anything you can find on windows+sass: http://www.impressivewebs.com/sass-on-windows/.  And if that fails, you try to find a Notepad++ discussion group, and if you still can't get an answer, then you say to yourself, "Self, Notepad++ sucks.  I'm not going to use it."

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution for anyone else having the same trouble on notepad++:

> Sass-Auto-Compile
>
> For using the Sass-Auto-Compile plugin, you first need to install
>   another plugin called jN. jN is a plugin for Notepad++, which executes
>   your JavaScript-scripts in the Notepad++ environment, meaning you can
>   write plugins in JavaScript
>
> this is the link :
>   http://www.ninjagame.de/blogContent/Sass-Auto-Compile.js
>
> To get the auto-compiling working, you need to do two things:
>
> Copy this script into the directory “Notepad++/plugins/jN/includes/” .
>   Now edit the script and change the variable pathToRubyBinDir to the
>   right value. Mine is: “C:/Program Files/Ruby193/bin/” .
>
> OPTIONAL: There are two more configuration variables:
>
> debugMode: can be true or false. In case of true, you will see the
>   command line, which calls the compiling process. You can see compiling
>   errors in this command line window.
>
> outputStyle: this determines, how your .css is going to look like.
>   (compressed, extended…). See the comments above this variable for more
>   information.

This guide is copied and pasted from http://deekaysblog.wordpress.com